# How to introduce an input in a C program through shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sh

When I execute the program in console I just do this:

```
./c1 2500
textfile.txt
```

and it just print a integer. The thing here is that I want to introduce 1000 textfiles as input so I made this script:

```
c=1
while [ $c -le 1000 ]
do
    ./c1 2500 >> sal.txt
    $c.txt 
    (( c++ ))
done
```

The trouble here is that the script is not putting the output in the file text because is not iterating as it should, I think the problem is when the name of the filetext is introduced as $c.txt, how can i solve this?
Thanks for reading

Comment: Is that textfile.txt in input or in output?

Comment: are you running the same program (`c1`) with the same argument (`2500`) 1000 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***$c.txt*** is not a command and the bash interpreter can't understand what that means
if you want to create a file, use **`touch [file]`**
or you want to copy a existing file to the destination, use **`cp [src_file] [dst_file]`**
so the code may like this:

```
    ./c1 2500 > $c.txt
```

or you may want to append the result to a file:

```
    ./c1 2500 > $c.txt
    cat $c.txt >> sal.txt
```

ps:
***`>`*** and ***`>>`*** both of these operators represent output redirection
***`>`*** writes the output to the file
***`>>`*** appends the output to the file
***`cat`*** concatenates files and print on the standard output

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.